# Magento 2.1 - Memory Leak in my getCollection function

Tags: magento2, blocks, collection, factory

So I'm creating a really simple module to read from a custom table. Nothing fancy, table has two rows:

```
+-----------+--------------+
+ status_id + status_label +
+-----------+--------------+
+ 1         + option 1     +
+-----------+--------------+
+ 2         + option 2     +
+-----------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to get them into a `<select>` element so I set up my Block to get the options:

```
public function getStatusOptions()
{
    return  $this->statusFactory->create()->getCollection();
}
```

`StatusFactory` gets auto generated by (I'm in developer mode so is automatic) fine which is good but when I try and use it in my template like this:

```
<select name="" id="my-select" class="select">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStatusOptions() as $k => $option) : ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $k; ?>">
            <?php var_dump($option); ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

but it returns a fatal error of: `Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400560128 bytes)`

but I'm not sure why .. Everywhere online seems to suggest this is the way to do it (and I'm almost 100% on it because Dependacy Injection is the way it seems with M2).

If you need more code let me know, or if you find a duplicate (I couldn't find a solution that worked for me) then please link :)

## UPDATE

I know `getCollection` works, made another function that also uses `->getSize()` and it returns the correct ammount of rows, so.. maybe I'm missing something for calling my collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thing I notice here is that you use the method for a loop; so every time the `foreach()` runs, a new collection object will be instantiated, which means - if I am correct - that every time the `foreach` will start new, and will run infinitely.

A better way would be to store the result in a variable:

```
<select name="" id="my-select" class="select">
    <?php
    $options = $this->getStatusOptions();
    foreach ($options as $k => $option) : ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $k; ?>">
            <?php var_dump($option); ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This way, the object will only be created once, the collection will only be loaded once and you're safe to go.

Another possibility is to set the collection as a property on your object; change the function as shown below:

```
public function getStatusOptions()
{
    if(is_null($this->_statusCollection) {
        $this->_statusCollection = $this->statusFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
    return $this->_statusCollection;
}
```

Again, you will have only one object instantiated.

You are correct that `getCollection()` returns a collection object, but deep inside the code the collection class implements the `ArrayAccess` interface (docs here: http://php.net/manual/de/class.arrayaccess.php), so it is loopable by `foreach()`.

Also keep in mind that `var_dump($option);` can consume a lot of memory if `$option` is an object that extends from a default Magento class. In this case, however, it should have a `debug()` method available, that will consume a lot less memory and can be used like `var_dump($option->debug());`.

Comment: ah fudge muffins this is correct! I should have assigned it to a var and looped the variable ! Can't believe I missed that haha will accept this as correct, as my answer is technically correct, but not the true solution to my error

Answer (score 1):

it turns out `->getCollection()` isn't neccesarily the collection data but the collection object. To get data use collection like this:

```
return $this->statusFactory->getCollection()->getData();
```